# How to use a Chef Windows reboot resource to reboot only once

Tags: windows, chef-infra, reboot

I'm currently attempting to use the reboot resource in a chef resource:

```
reboot 'ADS Install Complete' do
  action :nothing
  reason 'Cannot continue Chef run without a reboot.'
  only_if {reboot_pending?}
end

...

execute 'Initialize ADS Configuration INI' do
  command "\"#{node["ads-tfs-ini"]["tfsconfig_path"]}\" unattend \/create \/type:#{node["ads-tfs-ini"]["Scenario"]} \/unattendfile:\"#{node["ads-tfs-ini"]["unattend_file_path"]}\""
  only_if { ! "#{ENV['JAVA_HOME']}".to_s.empty? }
  notifies :request_reboot, 'reboot[ADS Install Complete]', :delayed
end
```

I am getting an endless loop of reboots (client reboots-->chef client runs-->chef client reruns the run_list--client reboots-->...).  How can I just reboot once?

Answer (score 0):

You could add some validation to check whether the computer has been rebooted once.

```
ruby_block "reboot" do
  unless File.exist?("C:\reboot") do
    block do
      Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('C:\reboot').write_file
      Chef::ShellOut.new("shutdown /r").run_command
    end
  end
end
```

This solution isn't really elegant, but it should work. The reboot is inside the ruby block which will only run if C:\reboot DOESN'T exist. If the file doesn't exist, the block will create the file and then call the reboot. On the second chef run, the file will exist so the reboot will not be triggered.

[Here is the documention regarding ruby_block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html)

Answer (score 0):

from [`reboot`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_reboot.html) chef resource:

> Use the reboot resource to reboot a node, a necessary step with some installations on certain platforms. This resource is supported for use on the Microsoft Windows, macOS, and Linux platforms.

```
reboot 'name' do
  action :reboot_now
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `only_if` guard in the `execute` resource makes execute resource run, if `ENV['JAVA_HOME']` **is not empty**. Very likely, that this environment variable is set and that's why your `execute` resource is run every time Chef runs, and triggers the reboot.

My guess, is you just actually need an opposite, run the resource, only if the variable **is empty**. For that you can just remove the `!` from the line.

```
only_if { ENV['JAVA_HOME'].to_s.empty? }
```

If my previous guess is wrong, then you need to change your `only_if` guard to something more robust. From the command line, I understand you create some configuration files, so you don't need to run `execute` resource, when you config files already exist:

```
not_if { ::File.exist?('/path/to/file/created/by/command') }
```